# Charging an Android Device

Tags: android, battery, batterylevel

Is there a possibility to change the battery level programmatically, I mean to charge it programatically by myself or is it a system call(android sees that a power device is connected and charges)?

I have the following use case:

There is one output(micro usb) that is connected to a usb hub with a possibility to connect many usb devices, one of that devices should be a power device.

I can see programmatically all the devices connected to my phone, but I cant realize at the moment how can i programmatically say the android: please charge from that usb device.

Is it a system call and I require the source code of the android os to be modified in the right way? I have already downloaded source code from https://source.android.com/ and run the make on these code, but can't get it to the eclipse - exceptions raised due to lack of resources :-)

Is it possible to completely remove the android os from a device and get a modified version by my own on it?

Thank you for all advices

Comment: Generally charging vs. sourcing power is ultimately under software control, in response to the extra ID pin being grounded or not.  But that software is below the level of Android, and not something that is going to be accessible to an application a device running a stock Android install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usb devices draw power from the usb host. When you connect peripherals to your phone it acts as a usb host. In that case the peripheral device draws power from your phone and not the other way.

I don't think a usb host can draw power from a device.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, just read about usb, the intention is not possible.

Comment: @niew You are welcome. Don't forget to accept my answer if you think it answered your question. It will help others reading your question in the future.